# Dynamic "Favorite" button - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have created a table which dynamically generates records using the "Infinite Loading" process, I have a button in my HTML Code which i need to use to allow users to add the item in their favourite - so this is my HTML code

```
@model List<PagesAuth.Models.Links.MLink>

@foreach (var I in Model)
{
    <tr> 
        <td class="v-align-top" id="itemcard">                
            <h4 class="card-title">
                @I._title 
                <small><cite>@I._tp_created.ToString("dd MMM yyyy")</cite> /small>
            </h4>            
            <div class="pull-right" id="options">
                <ul class="list-inline text-right" >                   
                    @if (I._tp_favourite == 0)
                    {
                    <li><button class="btn-link glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty" onclick="location.href='@Url.RequestContext .Action("_Fav", "Home", "@I._id")'"></button></li>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                  <li><button class="btn-link glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty" onclick="location.href='@Url.RequestContext .Action("_UnFav", "Home", "@I._id")'"></button></li>
                    }
                </ul>
            </div>    
        </div>

        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

I am trying to use "Favourite" button to allow user to add that website to their favourite list (I am ok with the DB updates etc)

```
<ul class="list-inline text-right" >                   
                    @if (I._tp_favourite == 0)
                    {
                    <li><button class="btn-link glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty" onclick="location.href='@Url.RequestContext .Action("_Fav", "Home", "@I._id")'"></button></li>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                  <li><button class="btn-link glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty" onclick="location.href='@Url.RequestContext .Action("_UnFav", "Home", "@I._id")'"></button></li>
                    }
                </ul>
```

- What I want to know is how to achieve this on user front-end - Like I thought I should just create a PartialView and make it child action only in my controller, send it ID and do DB Processing

  ```
  [ChildActionOnly]

  public ActionResult _Fav(int ID)

  {//Do DB Processing    


      return PartialView(ID);

  }
  ```

First of all the following does not work

```
onclick="location.href='@Url.RequestContext .Action("_UnFav", "Home", "@I._id")'"
```

Second, if I end up making this work, it will still refresh the page and I don't want that.

Is there a better way to achieve this

Cheers

Comment: I'd suggest using ajax to send the request on button click. From there you can handle the result. If successful, perform ui change to indicate `favourite`, else do nothing.

Comment: I also looked around and people do talk about using SignalR but for this small little thing, I don't want to use SignalR.

Comment: @JohnEphraimTugado where should i send request to , my controller's partialview or just a simple class, and how would the UI change will happen inside AJAX

Comment: Why would you want to use a partial view? what will you show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you want to use partial views but you can do it this way.

1. Use ajax to send request to controller action.
2. Handle action result using JavaScript.

View:

```
@model List<PagesAuth.Models.Links.MLink>

@foreach (var I in Model)
{
    <tr> 
        <td class="v-align-top" id="itemcard">                
            <h4 class="card-title">
                @I._title 
                <small><cite>@I._tp_created.ToString("dd MMM yyyy")</cite> /small>
            </h4>            
            <div class="pull-right" id="options">
                <ul class="list-inline text-right" >                   
                    @if (I._tp_favourite == 0)
                    {
                        <li><button class="btn-link glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty" onclick="Fav(@I._id)"></button></li>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <li><button class="btn-link glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty" onclick="UnFav(@I._id)"></button></li>
                    }
                </ul>
            </div>    
        </div>

        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

JS:

Here I am just alerting that the favorite action succeeded, else you have an array of string errors to work with. You could redirect or do some stuff, whichever you prefer.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function Fav(id) {
        var url = '@Url.Action("_Fav", "Home")';

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                id: id
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if(data.length == 0) // No errors
                    alert("Fave success!");
            },
            error: function (jqXHR) { // Http Status is not 200
            },
            complete: function (jqXHR, status) { // Whether success or error it enters here
            }
        }); 
    };

    function UnFav(id) {
        var url = '@Url.Action("_UnFav", "Home")';

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                id: id
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if(data.length == 0) // No errors
                    alert("Unfave success!");
            },
            error: function (jqXHR) { // Http Status is not 200
            },
            complete: function (jqXHR, status) { // Whether success or error it enters here
            }
        }); 
    };

</script>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult _Fav(int ID)
{
    List<string> errors = new List<string>(); // You might want to return an error if something wrong happened

    //Do DB Processing   

    return Json(errors, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult _UnFav(int ID)
{
    List<string> errors = new List<string>(); // You might want to return an error if something wrong happened

    //Do DB Processing   

    return Json(errors, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Ok, this makes so much sense, thank you so much for this, Although I am unable to trigger the click action for some reason  `<li><button class="btn-link glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty" onclick="Fav(@I._id)"></button></li>` with script as `@section script {}` and also added refrence to AJAX at the top `<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>`

Comment: removing the script from ` @section script {}` section fixed the issue :) thank you so much for your help ...