# Dynamic favorite button - ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, html, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I created a form where I get data from database using ASP.NET Core MVC and ADO.NET, in which I show the data using `foreach` loop. Now I tried to create a button of add to favourite but I do not understand how to create it because how can I add data into favourite list individually?

Here is my view markup:

```
<div class="filter_and_location" style="right: 0%;">
    <div class="property_information">
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <div class="home-info">
                <a href="#" class="home-images">
                    <img src="@item.pic1" />
                </a>
                <div class="home-data">
                    <div class="home-name">
                        <p>@item.tittle</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="price">
                        <p>@item.price</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="features">
                        <span>
                        @item.bedroom
                        @item.bathroom
                        </span>
                        <span>
                        2
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="desc">
                        @item.descrip
                    </div>
                    @*This is the Favourite Button*@
                    <div class="contact-save">
                        <a href="tel:=11111111111" class="phone_number">
                        <!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.1.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
                        </a>
                        <div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">
                            <a href="tel:+928754756478" class="phone_number">
                            </a>
                            <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">tel:+928754756478</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="popupmsg" onclick="myFunctionmsg()">
                            <a href="#" class="phone_number open_message"></a>
                            <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup1">abc123@exmaple.</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

I comment the line which I want to create the favourite button.

Here is my controller:

```
public IActionResult Rent(int PageNumber = 1)
{
    var data = rdb.GetDataHouse();

    ViewBag.Totalpages = Math.Ceiling(data.Count()/5.0);
    data = data.Skip((PageNumber - 1)*5).Take(5).ToList();

    return View(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your description and code don't convey the result you expect. Maybe you want to click the favorite button and retrieve a set of data corresponding to the Id in the database through the Id. I built a simple example, maybe what you want.

View:

Display the data on the page (I load the favorite from a hidden table):

```
<div class="filter_and_location" style="right: 0%;">
    <div class="property_information">
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <div class="home-info">
                    <div class="price">
                        <p>@item.Id</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="features">
                        <span>
                            @item.Name
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    @*This is the Favourite Button*@
                    <div class="contact-save">
                        <button id="@item.Id" onclick="test(@item.Id)" class="btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <table class="table" style="display:none;">
        <thread>
            <tr>
                <td>Id</td>
                <td>Name</td>
            </tr>
        </thread>
        <tbody id="tbody">
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<script>
    function test(id)
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "/Home/Index",
            data: { id: id },
            success: function (response) {
                var html = "<tr><td>" + response.id + "</td>"
                         + "<td>" + response.name + "</td></tr>";
                
                $("#tbody").append(html);
                $(".table").show();
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Controller:

Fetch the corresponding data from the database by receiving the Id, and then return to the table showing the favorite data in the view:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Index(int Id)
{
    //Match data with the same Id from the database
    //if necessary， you can create a new database and save it in the database
    var model = ...
    return Json(model);
}
```

Result:

Before adding favorites:

[image]

After adding favorites:

[image]
[image]

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46721729/dynamic-favorite-button-asp-net-mvc) is a case you can use as a reference.

Please let me know if this is what you want.

**Edit:**

You can change the class used by the button, these classes contain the default color. For example, add the line below in ajax success function:

```
$("#" + id).attr("class","btn-default");
```

You can also add `disabled` attribute to control the button to be disabled after one click:

```
$("#" + id).attr("disabled", true);
```

Comment: yes its nice but how can i pass more than one property means if want to pass id, name, description.

Comment: Are your id, name, description not the same record in the database? @Qasim Asghar

Comment: ok i understand i just want to know that how to change color button after submitting to show that its already submit

Comment: I updated my answer, you can have a try. @Qasim Asghar

Comment: Thanks but i use link and svg so have any solution for it

Comment: Please describe in detail. What effect do you want?

Comment: Thanks i remove my svg and put <i> tag for icon which resolve my issue.